# Change cluster name in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

How to **rename** the current cluster in elasticsearch config?

i want to rename the cluster without it going down if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are having multi nodes cluster means, you can try updating cluster names in config file & directory name (if replicas enabled) one by one nodes; which is similar to [rolling upgrade](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rolling-upgrades.html) of the Elasticsearch.

if you are using single node cluster means, you can attempt changing the cluster name in config file but restart of cluster will be needed to take effect change.

Comment: i have an existing ES with clusterName: x, i have updated the name to y in elasticsearch.yml but cannot see indices anymore, could you suggest ?

Comment: @LasitPant did you restart your nodes?

Comment: i did, i didn't change the cluster name on elasticsearch.yml file only,
i didn't make the changes (data_directory name) and hence i suspect no data was coming up

Answer (score 6):

Make edits in the `elasticsearch.yml` file. By default the `es` cluster name is `elasticsearch` and the `cluster.name` field in the yml file is commented out. So first uncomment it, then give a name and restart `es`.

[image]